# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in C Snapshot

Tags: c

> #### Snapshot
>
> **Introduction**
>
> Usual search engines receive a set of keywords and look for all the
> documents that contain these keywords. The documents are listed in the
> order of document significance. In this problem we consider the
> significance of a document for a set of keywords is given by the
> minimum number of words of the continuous piece of text that contains
> all the searched keywords. For instance: consider the keywords “2008”
> and “IEEEXtreme”, and the following two texts: “The registration for
> the 2008 edition of IEEEXtreme is now open” and “IEEEXtreme 2008
> edition is going to take place on March 8th 2008”. The significance of
> the first text is 4, and of the second one is 2. If any of the given
> words is not present in the text, the significance is zero.
>
> **Task**
>
> Please write a program that reads from the standard input a text in
> which the words are separated only by spaces, and finds the
> significance of text against the keywords given as the parameters to
> your program.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> For the input text:
>
> ```
> The registration for the 2008 edition of IEEEXtreme is now open
> ```
>
> your program executed as:
>
> ```
> > snapshot 2008 IEEEXtreme
> ```
>
> should write 4 on the standard output. Note: if not all
> the words are found, the program should return 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int compare(char *x, char *z) {
  int a = 0;
  if (strlen(x) == strlen(z)) {
    while (a < strlen(x)) {
      if (x[a] == z[a])
        a++;
      else
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
  }
}

int verify(int q, int n, char *v) {
  static int flag2 = 0;
  static int error = 0;

  if ((v[0] == '#') && (v[1] == '#') && (v[2] == '#') && (v[3] == '#')
      && (v[4] == '#')) {
    flag2 = 1;
  } else {
    error++;
  }

  if ((q = n - 1) && flag2 == 1 && error == 0)
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  char text[1000];
  char word[30];

  FILE *fp = fopen("filename", "r");

  int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, y = 1, w = 1, t = 1, flag = 0, signifiancia = 0,
      sucesso = 0;

  while (feof(fp))
    text[i++] = fgetc(fp);

  text[i] = '\0';

  while (text[j] != '\0') {
    if (text[j] == ' ') {
      j++;
      word[k] = '\0';
      k = 0;
      while (y < argc) {
        compare(argv[y], word);
        if (1) {
          flag = 1;
          argv[y] = "#####";
          signifiancia++;
          y++;
        } else {
          if (flag = 1)
            signifiancia++;
          y++;
        }
      }
    } else {
      word[k] = text[j];
      j++;
      k++;
    }
    while (w < argc) {
      verify(t, argc, argv[w]);
      t++;
      if (1) {
        sucesso++;
        printf("%d", signifiancia);
      }
    }
  }
  if (sucesso == 0)
    printf("0");
}
```

The error given is:
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Strap this into your debugger and find out more about the crash. A segmentation fault is almost always accessing an invalid pointer, or using an array out of bounds.

Comment: Tip: Get out of the habit of declaring your variables in a giant jumble. Declare them *where they are used* and as close as possible to their first usage.

Comment: while(feof(fp)) is always **doubly** wrong. You probably meant `while (!feof(fp))` which would just be always **singly** wrong :D

Comment: The problem is actually very simple: you're throwing **all the code** you could imagine at once into the file and then it doesn't work. Work in small increments and verify that they do indeed work as intended.

Comment: Hm. You never store or check the return values of `compare` and `verify`. The `if (1) ...` after these calls does not mean "if `verify`/`compare` returned 1", it means "always do this", because 1 as a condition is considered true.

Answer (score 2):

At least these problems:

**Missing return**

When `if (strlen(x) == strlen(z))` is false, function does not return anything.

Yet calling code does not use the return value anyways.

**Assignment rather than compare**

```
     if (flag = 1)
```

**Too many loops**

Code iterates once [too often](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

```
while (feof(fp))
  text[i++] = fgetc(fp);
```

**Infinite loop**

Once `while (w < argc) {` loop is entered, it appears to iterate infinitely - likely leading to UB.

**Failure to prevent buffer over-runs**